# Overleaf warning: \declareDelimAlias* is deprecated. How to fix that?

Tags: biblatex, errors, apa-style, auxiliary-files

I'm working with overleaf on a Mac and I recently got a new yellow warning which I don't quite understand. It says

```
Package biblatex Warning: The starred command '\DeclareDelimAlias*' is deprecated. Use the unstarred version '\DeclareDelimAlias' instead.
```

How can I fix that error?

Edit:

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber, sortlocale=de]{biblatex}




\begin{document}
Hello
\end{document}
```

I am on texlive version 2022.

Comment: Can you make a minimal working example that allows us to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Nope, that file doesn't exist. Ill try to make an MWE.

Comment: wait a sec: you mentioned overleaf. Can you clarify if you are using overleaf in a web browser or are you compiling your files locally on your computer?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz im using overleaf in the browser. Safari.

Comment: Ah, this uses files installed on the overleaf server, nothing on your local computer. Please make a small test file that reproduces the warning, we might then be able to tell you if there is a way to fix it.

Comment: Can you open the sidebar of your overleaf project and check which version of texlive you use? In my texlive2022, the apa.bbx file has already been fixed to use `\DeclareDelimAlias` instead of `\DeclareDelimAlias*`

Comment: (I suggest you remove the second part of your question about finding the file, that's not really relevant to the actual problem)

Comment: Okay, i made an MWE. I am on texlive version 2022.

Comment: Thanks! Looks as if the texlive version of overleaf is a bit outdated there. In real texlive this was already fixed.

Comment: So there is nothing I can do then? I need to wait for the overleaf people to fix stuff? I am maybe a bit too much of a perfectionist for being a texguy :D that error annoys me :D

Comment: I would suggest to ignore this warning until overleaf rolls out texlive2023 (yes, this will take some while, but the warning about deprecation just tells you that the command won't be around for much longer, which isn't a problem as long as biblatex/biber isn't updated, which overleaf will only do if they also update apa.bbx) or upload  the current version of `apa.bbx`to your project : https://www.overleaf.com/read/jtfqqdzdwmgq

Comment: Where would I need to upload that? @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz

Comment: for reference, this was fixed in https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/commit/6e66dfb0af04502a3a2757cec1e6261c4ea4669d

Comment: You can get the file from https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/blob/master/tex/latex/biblatex-apa/bbx/apa.bbx and upload it into your overleaf project, in the same folder as your main file, like done here: https://www.overleaf.com/project/63060ed763e5950caa78ad56

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick :-)

Comment: In my case I solved the error because simply using [style=authoryear,natbib]

Comment: IMHO this does not really fix the issue using `style=apa`, but use another style, which is not APA. If the apa style is needed, the better suggestion is to ignore the harmless warning (see the comments to the other answer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This warning has been fixed in https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/commit/6e66dfb0af04502a3a2757cec1e6261c4ea4669d which is available via texlive in version 9.16 (from 2022/06/22) of apa.bbx.

The texlive2022 version of overleaf only has v9.15 (2021/12/24).

You can work around the problem by uploading the current version of apa.bbx from https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/blob/master/tex/latex/biblatex-apa/bbx/apa.bbx to your overleaf project

Comment: Just to add that the warning is perfectly benign and can be ignored. With the version of `biblatex` that is on Overleaf, the deprecated starred version of `\DeclareDelimAlias*` should still work as intended.

Comment: @moewe Apparently, ignoring wasn't an option :) https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/655035/overleaf-warning-declaredelimalias-is-deprecated-how-to-fix-that/655042?noredirect=1#comment1632438_655035

Comment: At the moment, the current `biblatex-apa` cannot be uploaded to Overleaf, because it assumes a newer `biblatex` and Biber than Overleaf's TeX Live 2022 has. (But even if it did work, I usually don't think it is a good idea to upload loads of packages to Overleaf projects. Of course it might be your only option if you absolutely need the fix on Overleaf now. If you just want to avoid a harmless warning, I'd say it's not worth it. But for more important stuff, things might be different.)

Comment: When will this be fixed? Meanwhile it's a year later.

Comment: @jay.sf This has been fixed since June 2022. Even the notoriously out of date version of overleaf now has texlive2023 available which contains the new version.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Really, for some reason I still get the message on overleaf.

Comment: @jay.sf Did you switch to texlive2023?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz How doing on overleaf?

Comment: @jay.sf You can select the version in the left sidebar

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz TY!