# Do "Author et al., 2020, 2021, 2022" instead of "Author et al., 2020; Author et al., 2022; Author et al., 2021" when using APA with BibLaTex

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I'm currently facing undefined behaviour when compiling my thesis.

When compiling in Overleaf
`\parencite{wolf2020bodyperception,wolf2021embodiment,wolf2022holographic}`, I'm getting the results

> Wolf et al., 2020; Wolf et al., 2022; Wolf et al., 2021

in the text.

When compiling the same file in my offline environment, I get

> Wolf et al., 2020, 2021, 2022

as the result.

I assume this is due to different package version between the environments that are using different default values, but I can't figure out which `biblatex` setting is defining this behaviour.

Here is my `biblatex` config:

```
\usepackage[
style=apa,              % Citestyle
isbn=false,             % Hides ISBN
doi=true,               % Shows DOI
pagetracker=true,       
autocite=inline,        % Defines \autocite as inline=\parancite
block=space,            % Small space between fields
backref=true,           % Show pages where ref is used
date=year,              % Date format
backend=biber,
uniquelist=false,       % Adds letters for non-unique authors within a year
]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-apa}
```

The list of further authors differs in `wolf2020bodyperception`, `wolf2021embodiment`, `wolf2022holographic` - only the first author is always the same.

```
@inproceedings{wolf2020bodyperception,
  author    = {Wolf, Erik and Döllinger, Nina and Mal, David and Wienrich, Carolin and Botsch, Mario and Latoschik, Marc Erich},
  booktitle = {2020 IEEE International Symposium on Mixed and Augmented Reality (ISMAR)},
  title     = {Body Weight Perception of Females using Photorealistic Avatars in Virtual and Augmented Reality},
  year      = {2020},
  pages     = {583-594},
  doi       = {10.1109/ISMAR50242.2020.00071},
  publisher = {IEEE},
  address = {New York, NY, USA},
}
@inproceedings{wolf2021embodiment,
  author    = {Wolf, Erik and Merdan, Nathalie and Döllinger, Nina and Mal, David and Wienrich, Carolin and Botsch, Mario and Latoschik, Marc Erich},
  booktitle = {2021 IEEE Virtual Reality and {3D} User Interfaces (VR)},
  title     = {The Embodiment of Photorealistic Avatars Influences Female Body Weight Perception in Virtual Reality},
  year      = {2021},
  pages     = {65-74},
  doi       = {10.1109/VR50410.2021.00027},
  publisher = {IEEE},
  address = {New York, NY, USA},
}
@inproceedings{wolf2022holographic,
  author    = {Wolf, Erik and Fiedler, Marie Luisa and Döllinger, Nina and Wienrich, Carolin and Latoschik, Marc Erich},
  booktitle = {2022 IEEE Conference on Virtual Reality and {3D} User Interfaces (VR)},
  title     = {Exploring Presence, Avatar Embodiment, and Body Perception with a Holographic Augmented Reality Mirror},
  year      = {2022},
  pages     = {350--359},
  doi       = {10.1109/VR51125.2022.00054},
  publisher = {IEEE},
  address = {New York, NY, USA},
}
```

Can anyone advise me on how to always get

> Wolf et al., 2020, 2021, 2022

Comment: Can you show us the relevant `.bib` entries as well, please? Ideally in a fully compilable example document: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/. Can you also find out which version of `biblatex-apa` you are using? (Look for the version of `apa.bbx` reported in the `.log` file for example.) Note that if you want real APA style you should not (have to) use any of the options you are passing except of course `style=apa,` and `backend=biber,`. The `\DeclareLanguageMapping` hasn't been needed for `biblatex-apa` for at least a couple of years.

Comment: According to https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/issues/150 `biblatex-apa` v9.16 or above should produce correct APA behaviour, which *probably* coincides with what you want (give or take the exact contents of the `.bib` entries).

Comment: Overleaf uses in their 2022 version biblatex-apa v9.15, my offline environment uses v9.16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a deviation of older versions of `biblatex-apa` from APA style that was reported in https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/issues/150 and fixed in `biblatex-apa` v9.16 (2022-06-22). Presumably your local TeX system is up-to-date enough to have this version. Overleaf does not have it yet, not even in their TeX Live 2022 system (the newest at the point of writing this answer).

While the fix for the reported issue is fairly simple (https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/commit/6f36071a3bb0c1d7e5d71a2afb42d75bd4a67e06) - if a a bit lengthy -, there were related issues (most notably https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/issues/152) in v9.15 and below that required new features in `biblatex` and Biber and hence cannot be replicated on Overleaf until they update their TeX system. (Updating `biblatex` styles or - more generally speaking - LaTeX packages is sort of possible on Overleaf by just uploading the relevant files into your project. I absolutely do not recommend this, because it can cause confusion and a huge mess, but sometimes this is the best way to get the desired result. Here, however, you also need new version of `biblatex` and the Biber *binary* - that doesn't work via uploading.)

For now you probably have to live with the undesirable output on Overleaf and will just have to compile the final version of your work locally. Sorry.

Comment: Indeed, while Overleaf uses in their 2022 version biblatex-apa v9.15, my offline environment uses v9.16. With the latter one, I'm getting desired results.

It has been [suggested](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/655035/overleaf-warning-declaredelimalias-is-deprecated-how-to-fix-that) to add the apa.bbx to the Overleaf project, but this is causing further problems for me.

Comment: For working on the Thesis, it's no problem, and I can use the offline environment to generate the final print pdf. However, I was worried about the unclear behaviour I was facing.

Comment: @ErikWolf Yes, you cannot just upload `apa.bbx`, because that relies on a newer version of `biblatex` and Biber than Overleaf has.

Comment: I left [a comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/655035/overleaf-warning-declaredelimalias-is-deprecated-how-to-fix-that#comment1670531_655042) under the answer you linked to warn people that uploading `apa.bbx` won't work at the moment.